# Storing Statistics in Java Calculator Program

Tags: java

Creating a basic post fix expression evaluator/calculator program in Java using Eclipse. I want to be able to store some statistics (listed below)

•   The highest overall result value
•   The lowest overall result value
•   The aggregate value (all answers added together)
•   The average answer (from all answers of all expressions)
•   Total invalid expressions entered
•   Total valid expressions entered

Current code: http://pastebin.com/EijjR6jq

Any guidance appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You need to be more specific in your question...

Comment: Post the code here on SO and tell us where you're stuck

Comment: Apologies, new to posting on here. Says my entry is too many characters so I can't post the code here.

Comment: The help center is there to help you. Please use it. Take the tour while you are at it.

Comment: Basically I wish to store some statistics in variables and print them before the program terminates. I am aware of how to do that however I'm having difficulty storing the highest and lowest answers.

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution would be to create an arraylist to store the values (before printing). This arraylist will contain all of the values which you have gotten so far. Sorting it will get you the highest/lowest overall value, summing it up & dividing that sum by the number of elements in the arraylist will get you the aggregate value & average answer.

As for the invalid and valid expressions, counters could be implemented to keep track of those. Increment the respective counter (valid/invalid) depending on the expression entered.

So for example, it will look something like below.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);    
int invalidNumberExpressions = 0; //counter for invalids
int validNumberExpressions = 0; //counter for valids
ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<String>(); //Arraylist for calculated values

while (true) {

... //Omitted

if ("+".equals(part3)) {
    // Note that your calculation ends up with a string, and not a float
    values.add(part1 + " " + part3 + " " + part2 + " " + " = " + (number1 + number2));
    System.out.println(values.get(validNumberExpressions));
    validNumberExpressions++;
}

// Omitted
```

Could also consider using switch statements & refactoring out the common section of code in both parts into another method so you don't have to repeat the whole section twice. Looks cleaner, too.

Something like the below for the switch statement. I'll leave the refactoring part to you.

```
switch (part3) {
    case "+":   values.add(part1 + " " + part3 + " " + part2 + " " + " = " + (number1 + number2));
                System.out.println(values.get(validNumberExpressions));
                validNumberExpressions++;
                break;

    ... //other cases here
}
```